# How would you express the sentiment of "Happy New Era"

Tags: translation, set-phrases, culture

Something like 良いお時代を。? Or would you specifically say 令和?

If not that, what would be a literal English translation?

Comment: Traditionally, this event is not a 'happy' one.

Comment: You could say 明るい時代になりますように

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good afternoon, I was curious as well as what would be better to say so I looked online to see what Japanese people were saying about the new era. No one really said congratulations or happy new era, but I found one blog where the writer said something like "Congratulations for the new Era, 令和!"
She wrote:

> 令和、[新]{あたら}しい[時代]{じだい}の[幕開]{まくあ}けおめでとうございます！

[Here](https://ameblo.jp/100suiren/entry-12451550121.html) is a link to the posters blog where I found this sentence.

Hope it helps.